# Xcode become very slow. How to make it fast?

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, macos

I use both Xcode 4.6 and Xcode 5.0 for my work. Of late I have observed that it has become very slow. If I open two projects in two windows, switching from one window to another takes way too long. This slowing down is specific to only Xcode as other apps run just fine.

Any insights into how to fix it?

PS: its not related to derived-data or archives. its slow even after emptying both.

Comment: Have you rebooted any time in the past several months?

Comment: How old is your mac ?

Comment: I am using late 2009 mac mini (2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo). 4 gigs RAM

Comment: @Hot Licks: Thanks for comment. I regular reboot my comp every week at least.

Comment: I suspect that IDESubversion to be the culprit. Let me turn it off.

Comment: From my personal experience Xcode and OSX are consuming more and more resources. Recently I moved from old Core 2 Duo with 4 GB RAM to a new machine with i7 and 32 GB RAM and now Xcode is restarting faster after crashed :-)

Comment: @Anshu: Time flies when you're having fun. It might simply be a side effect of your machine being nearly 5 years old.

Comment: More RAM helped me with this.

Comment: Yes , Ram its your bottleneck here, try with 8GB and you will be fine,

Comment: @Mario GT. RAM is not a problem here. As described in my answer below, the IDESubversion plugin was the problem.

Comment: @Anshu I can say that it works fine with 16GB, but I also run some heavy apps and memory so cheap these days, that I decided to waste money a bit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voila. Its working fine now. I don't see any slow-down while context switching between two Xcode windows or working within Xcode in general.

I found 2 main culprits for Xcode slowing down.

1) IDESubversion plugin. I guess this got added from Xcode4.0 onwards. I turned it off.
Here's how to do it:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESubversion.ideplugin
```

Rename IDESubversion to something like IDESubversion-disabled. Keep extension unchanged.

CAUTION:Please note that I do not use Xcode provided subversion as it is a real CPU and RAM hog. I use Versions. If you use the Xcode provided subversion control, you should not do this step.

2) Delete project.xcworkspace file. In Finder, right-click on YourProjectName.xcodeproj

Select "Show Package Contents" and delete project.xcworkspace.

After doing these two things, my Xcode runs just fine. No slowdown whatever.

PS: RAM is not the root cause in everything that causes a computer to slow down (since most comments suggest that). Even in Xcode3, the in-built subversion used to be a CPU hog to the point of being a nuisance.

Credits:
I found this link helpful in coming to above conclusion:
[Link 1](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/off-topic/82271-is-xcode-4-really-supposed-to-be-this-slow.html)